# Looker studio: How to apply filter on metrics, and not on the whole chart

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a table where the "Landing pages" are the dimensions, and the metrics are based on the "Session Medium".

|  | organic | email | referral | social |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| landing page 1 | views count | views count | views count | views count |
| landing page 2 | views count | views count | views count | views count |
| landing page 3 | views count | views count | views count | views count |
| landing page 4 | views count | views count | views count | views count |

For instance, let's say we have Landing page X, which received 2000 views from Organic, 120 views from Email, 156 from Referral, and so on. The goal is to generate a comprehensive report that helps analyze the performance of each page in relation to each medium.

I'm trying to solve that, but unsuccessfully.

The best idea I have come up with so far, is to create a field formula, for the VIEW metric, that will filter (include) only the VIEWS for a specific Medium; however, I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax, or if it's possible at all.

In my imagination, the formula needs to be something like the following:

`if(session medium = 'organic', views, null)`

I'm aware of the fact that I can use a filter, but since the filter is appliable on a whole chart, it doesn't serve well in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem.

Have used a `pivot-table`, instead of a normal table, and used `landing page` for row dimension, and `session medium`, for column dimension.

[image]

Worked perfectly